# simple app that can be downloaded and installed to the android phone and once clicked on the app will open a URL in the default browser of the phone

Tags: android

simple app that can be downloaded and installed to the android phone and once clicked on the app will open a URL in the default browser of the phone. pls tell me how to start this application?

Answer (score 3):

At first try with Google before posting in here. Because you are idle person [ i think :) ] I am also giving you the solution also.

In your main activity's onCreate method just use these codes to open google's website :

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: followed by finish() if you want your app to stop executing after opening the browser.

Comment: just move the startActivity into the code block and it's golden ;)